# Configure depth overflow value - Start-Job

Tags: powershell

I have a recursive function that is executed around 750~ times - iterating over XML files and processing. The code is running using `Start-Job`

Example below:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

    function Test-Function {

        Param 
        (
            $count
        )
        Write-Host "Count is: $count"

        $count++
        Test-Function -count $count
    }
    Test-Function -count 1

}
```

Output:

```
$job | Receive-Job
Count is: 224
Count is: 225
Count is: 226
Count is: 227
The script failed due to call depth overflow.
```

The depth overflow occurs at 227 consistently on my machine. If I remove `Start-Job`, I can reach 750~ (and further). I am using jobs for batch processing.

Is there a way to configure the depth overflow value when using `Start-Job`?

Is this a limitation of PowerShell Jobs?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I am seeing the error with Windows PowerShell 5.1

Comment: What happens if you give each job a different name? I.e. the iteration it's on, or something similar?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Same issue occurs unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't answer about the specifics of call depth overflow limitations in PS 5.1 / 7.2 but you could do your recursion based-off a Queue within the job.

So instead of doing the recursion within the function, you do it from outside (still within the job though).

Here's what this look like.

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
$Queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::new()

    function Test-Function {

        Param 
        (
            $count
        )
        Write-Host "Count is: $count"

        $count++
        # Next item to process.
        $Queue.Enqueue($Count)
    }
    
    # Call the function once
    Test-Function -count 1
    # Process the queue
    while ($Queue.Count -gt 0) {
        Test-Function -count $Queue.Dequeue()
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

[.net Queue class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: That's great! Was not aware of a `queue` class..

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer that would solve the problem but rather an informative one. You could use an instance of the PowerShell SDK's [`[powershell]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell) class instead of `Start-Job`, which can handle more levels of recursion (by a big amount) in case it helps, here are my results:

| Technique | Iterations | PowerShell Version | Operating System |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `Start-Job` | 226~ | 5.1 | Windows 10 |
| `Start-Job` | 2008~ | 7.2.1 | Linux |
| PowerShell Instance | 4932~ | 5.1 | Windows 10 |
| PowerShell Instance | 11193~ | 7.2.1 | Linux |

- Code to reproduce

```bash
$instance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
    function Test-Function {
        Param($Count)

        Write-Host "Count is: $count"
        $count++
        Test-Function -count $count
    }

    Test-Function -Count 1
})

$async = $instance.BeginInvoke()

while(-not $async.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(200)) { }

$instance.Streams.Information[-1]
$instance.Dispose()
```