# Powershell Custom Recursion and BeginInvoke()

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, recursion

I need some help with a async Powershell call that fails with either (1) max recursion depth exceeded or (2) invalid input argument.

The basic setup is as follows...

- Coding and debugging done in VSCode
- Powershell version is 5.1.19041 - desktop edition
- Function to connect to SSAS server
- Recursive function called by first function to convert object to XML
- Create a Powershell session to execute the functions with parameters
- BeginInvoke(), wait for completion, process results

Is there something with the async call that is messing with my code such that the comparison between $*NestLevel* and $MaxDepth is invalid or that $MaxDepth is set to 0?

I've gone over this a hundred times and I don't see anywhere $MaxDepth is ever set to anything below 1.  The "if ( $*NestLevel* -gt $MaxDepth ) { return }" should terminate recursion but doesn't seem like it is.

Am I missing something?

Code example...

```
function Test-Recursion {
            Param (
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
                $InputObject,
        
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
                [ValidateRange(1,100)]
                [Int16] $MaxDepth   = 2
            )
        
            [Int16] $_NestLevel_ += 1
            if ( $_NestLevel_ -gt $MaxDepth ) { return }
        
            "<item><nest_level>$($_NestLevel_)</nest_level><max_depth>$($MaxDepth)</max_depth></item>"
            & $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock -InputObject $InputObject -MaxDepth $MaxDepth
        }
        
function Get-Info {
                Param (
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                    [String] $HostName,
        
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                    [ScriptBlock] $ConvertTo
                )
                
                $some_collection | `
                ForEach-Object {
                    @(
                        $_as  | ForEach-Object {
                            & $ConvertTo -InputObject $_ -MaxDepth 3 
                        }
                    ) | Sort-Object
                }
        }
        
        # this code fails with either...
        #   - excessive recursion depth
        #   - invalid $MaxDepth value of 0
        try {
            $_ps    = [powershell]::Create()
            $null   = $_ps.AddScript(${function:Get-Info})
            $null   = $_ps.AddParameter('HostName', 'some_server_name')
            $null   = $_ps.AddParameter('ConvertTo', ${function:Test-Recursion}) 
        
            $_handle    = $_ps.BeginInvoke()
            while ( -Not $_handle.IsCompleted ) {
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            }
        
            $_result    = $_ps.EndInvoke($_handle)
            $_result
        } catch {
            $_
        } finally {
            $_ps.Dispose()
        }
        
        # this code works as expected
        $items = Get-Info -HostName 'some_server_name' -ConvertTo ${function:Test-Recursion}
        $items.table_data
```

Comment: You might be facing a "depth overflow", you should consider using a `Queue` instead of recursion, see a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71366308/15339544

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I know I'm dealing with "depth overflow".  What I don't understand is why it only happens with an async call but works when called synchronously.  I'll look into the Queue option you mentioned.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to go into the details of what you're looking to accomplish with these functions, will just point out what the issue is, your [`powershell` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) is running out of stack memory due to an **infinite loop** caused by your `Test-Recursion` function not **knowing when to stop**, hence the addition of a **new parameter** (`[Int16] $NestingLevel`) that will be passed as argument on *each recursive call*:

```bash
function Test-Recursion {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateRange(1,100)]
        [Int16] $MaxDepth = 2,

        [Parameter(DontShow)]
        [Int16] $NestingLevel
    )

    [Int16] $NestingLevel += 1
    if ( $NestingLevel -gt $MaxDepth ) {
        return
    }

    "<item><nest_level>$NestingLevel</nest_level><max_depth>$MaxDepth</max_depth></item>"
    Test-Recursion -InputObject $InputObject -MaxDepth $MaxDepth -NestingLevel $NestingLevel
}

Test-Recursion -InputObject hello -MaxDepth 3
```

It is also worth noting that your recursive function can be simplified with a `while` loop:

```bash
function Test-Recursion {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateRange(1,100)]
        [Int16] $MaxDepth = 2,

        [Parameter(DontShow)]
        [Int16] $NestingLevel
    )

    while($NestingLevel++ -lt $MaxDepth) {
        "<item><nest_level>$NestingLevel</nest_level><max_depth>$MaxDepth</max_depth></item>"
    }
}
```

---

Regarding your latest comment:

> The root call initializes the variable to 1. Recursive calls would increment the variable and effectively provide a way to check the current nesting level.

No, the variable lives on each call of the function and then **the incremented value is lost after a recursive call**. You can however initialize the variable in the [`$script:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#scope-modifiers) and then it would work:

```bash
[Int16] $script:_NestLevel_ += 1
```

On a personal note, I do not like having `$script:` scoped variables inside my functions, there are better ways to do it in my opinion.

An easy way to demonstrate this is by modifying the function to output `$_NestLevel_` on each call, as-is, you would see an infinite amount of `1` being displayed to your console.

```bash
function Test-Recursion {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateRange(1,100)]
        [Int16] $MaxDepth = 2
    )

    [Int16] $_NestLevel_ += 1
    if ( $_NestLevel_ -gt $MaxDepth ) { return }
    $_NestLevel_
    & $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock -InputObject $InputObject -MaxDepth $MaxDepth
}
```

Comment: I am under the impression the "[Int16] $NestingLevel += 1" would result in a function scoped variable.  The root call initializes the variable to 1.  Recursive calls would increment the variable and effectively provide a way to check the current nesting level.  Am I misunderstanding how variable scoping works?  I will try your recommendation.  Thanks again.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it would __only work__ if you change the scope of that variable: `[Int16] $script:_NestLevel_ += 1` as-is, the variable lives on each call of the function and then is lost on each call of the function

Comment: @AlwaysLearning hopefully the update on my answer helps you clarifying it

Comment: The script behavior has changed for the better.  At least I'm making progress now.  Thanks.